# Is it efficient that I store my users login status in the database (mongoDB) to know when to redirect them to the login page?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, ejs

If not, what other ways can I use?

Can you, if possible to redirect me to a source code that does this?

Comment: What is the "login status"? If a user is logged in that should be detectable via cookies or something and you can redirect them.

Comment: By login status, I mean if they are logged in or not to see whether to redirect them to the login page. I am storing it in the database, and if they closes the tab, the login status becomes false. This is very inefficient. Thank you for your help! I'll checkout the cookies thing.

Comment: If you want the user to effectively log out as soon as they close the current tab, you might want to use session cookies and some sort of server-side sessions. You should also consider [JWTs](https://jwt.io/). They will help you keep your backend stateless, while ensuring server-side-like security.

Comment: Will do that, thank you!